# Restful WebService without annotations in eclipse using java

Tags: android, rest, ibm-rad

We are creating an application in android which will invoke Restful webservices.But here the problem is the web services should of without annotations as we are going to deploy them in RAD(Rational Application Developer),which is not going to recognise the annotations as it is IBM specific.So We need Restful web services without annotations. 
    Any example source code will be very thankful

Regards,
badri

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about hosting web services or calling web services?

If you're hosting, aren't you hosting in a Servlet container? All of the major Java frameworks work within modern Servlet containers. And the jars specific to the framework do all of the annotation processing, not the Servlet container. The only real requirement is Java 5 so that you have access to annotations at all.

If you have to use Java 1.4, then you should just use an ancient action framework like Struts 1 (which I wouldn't wish on anybody). Otherwise, you're back to raw servlets, which isn't completely awful to create web services.

Of course if you're not using Servlets at all, then basically nothing out there is going to help you since Servlets are the dominant Java web paradigm.